# React not seeing changes

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm

Has anyone else had an experience where react or vscode don't seem to see the changes you have made. It renders old code to the browser. How can I fix this?

I tried to restart VSCode, tried npm start again. No success

Comment: Could be stale browser cache.

Comment: Could you make sure that you are running the `npm start` on right project root path? And also did you checked opening project under incognito mode in the browser?

Comment: I tried incognito mode. Did not help. I don't know what you mean by right project root path.

Comment: did you save your changes in vscode?

Comment: Try checking makeing changes in some other editor, and check if you are making changes on the same repo and check if app is runnig on the same port

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had written the same piece of code twice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).